# framed.sty not found after switching from OS X to Linux

Tags: texlive, debian

I transitioned from OS X to Debian Linux. I have freshly installed TeX live, and I want to compile some tex files now which were running before on OS X.

For example, there is a file which uses a standard Springer template, but I end up with the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/....../foobar.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(./svmult.cls
Document Class: svmult 2007/06/25 v5.4 
Springer Verlag global LaTeX document class for multi authored books
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))

! LaTeX Error: File `framed.sty' not found.
```

(I compile using Gummi).

Is there a package which I am missing? I ran `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`, but this was already completely installed.

---

According to [this page](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/texlive-latex-base/filelist), Debian 6 has a lot of files in `tex/latex/ltxmisc/`, including the `framed.sty`. However, on my Debian Jessie (upcoming 8), there are only few files in that directory:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ltxmisc/
total 68
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9956 Jan 13  2006 abstbook.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1683 Jan 13  2006 beletter.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3348 Jan 13  2006 bibcheck.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1125 Jan 13  2006 concrete.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6489 Jan 13  2006 flashcard.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8608 Jan 13  2006 iagproc.cls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  772 Jan 13  2006 linsys.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1388 Jan 13  2006 mitpress.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6725 Jan 13  2006 thrmappendix.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2103 Jan 13  2006 topcapt.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2847 Jan 13  2006 vrbexin.sty
```

Comment: Personally, I always favour the vanilla TeX Live instead of the one packaged into a Linux distro. `:)` Still, I believe `framed` is probably in the `extra` stuff, so maybe `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` might help.

Comment: @PauloCereda - great, 565 MB later and `framed.sty` is there. I also needed package `texlive-bibtex-extra` because of a subsequent `biblatex.sty` not found error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

and you have everything.

Comment: Why so many gigabytes for one package?
I use quite a lot of packages, but not a full install of texlive. If I were to install texlive-full:
"Need to get 2,278 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,220 MB of additional disk space will be used."
4GB more... add to that all the time and bandwidth and disk usage spent for updates. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

installs framed.sty and other stuff, in my case totaling 512 MB

Comment: Even though the question mentions Debian, Arch users might benefit from knowing the package is called `texlive-latexextra` there.

Answer (score 0):

`tlmgr install framed` should do it.